# Visual Basic 6 form

Tags: vb6

How can I know that the form (other than the one I'm working upon) is open or closed?

Answer (score 7):

You have to distinguish between **Loaded** and **Visible**.

- For visiblility just check the `Visible` property (noting that doing so for an unloaded form will cause it to become loaded).
- For the loading state unfortunately there is no property. You have to iterate over all forms, and look whether your form is contained in the list of loaded forms:

  ```
  Public Function IsFormLoaded(FormToCheck As Form) As Boolean
    Dim F As Form 
    For Each F In Forms
      If F Is FormToCheck Then
        IsFormLoaded = True
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next
  End Sub
  ```

The global collection `Forms` contains all currently loaded forms.

Answer (score 3):

You can search the Forms collection

```
Dim aForm
For Each aForm In Forms
  If aForm Is Form1 Then
    MsgBox "Found Form1"
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If the form is in your application, you can simply track its state internally.  After all-- you control the points in code when it can be created or destroyed.